# Can anyone tell me the reason as to why Windows applications have to send data through Multicast 224.0.0.1 and etc?

Tags: networking, windows-8, google-chrome, multicast

So I have DNS Client, IGMP, and UPnP all disabled in Windows 8 yet Windows applications such as Chrome, GoogleUpdate, and Windows Activation executable still tries so hard to send outbound UDP frames to 224.0.0.1 even though I just connected a modem with no Internet connection and no other device connected to it.

To me, these applications sending these multicast traffic is like saying to the multicast group "Hey I'm using Google Chrome", "Hey I'm about to update my Google Chrome", "Hey my Windows is not yet activated". From a security point of view, this is bad, real bad. Like why in the world would these things have to send multicast traffic if you haven't even told them to do so for a specific purpose?

With this in mind, I would like to kindly ask if anyone out there actually knows for what purpose was this design implemented and for what purpose would apps like the one I mentioned above would need to perform multicast communications.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the specific UDP traffic that you're talking about, and can you attach it to the question somehow?

Comment: Sadly I don't have a sample with me right now and I was able to find out about all of these through logs created by norton firewall.

Comment: The traffic however, is generated within a split second of detecting a change in network adapter due to connecting my modem to it. I suppose I'll get wireshark and get a packet capture uploaded.

Comment: My first guess is some form of network identification.  224.0.0.1 is the multicast address for all nodes in the local multicast domain (essentially, everything you can reach through symmetric (not NAT) routing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that those were malicious traffic as not all those apps should be sending outbound multicast traffic.

Comment: Can you share what is what you found?

Comment: I don't have specifics on what infected my PC but it definitely starts as soon as I connect one of my network devices and it only happens with this device while it doesn't with the others. Did this on a Windows setup with multicast, IGMP, UpNP fully disabled on regedit, gpedit, network adapter settings; basically everywhere possible yet it's ignored as soon as I connect this device.
So I suspect the device has already been pwned.

Comment: Malwarebytes antimalware to the rescue! :)